# Casting a Delegate to a Generic delegate in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting, delegates

### Introduction

I'm using delegates to pass along and store styling logic for individual form `Control`s. For example, I have a delegate containing some `Button`-styling logic like this:

```
button.BackColor = Color.Red;
button.ForeColor = Color.White;
button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Of course there are many different other type of controls, like Labels, Panels, etc. So to store all these delegates I use a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>`.

Although, the delegate itself looks like this:

```
delegate void StyleDel<in T>(T control) where T : Control;
```

So in order to use the logic inside the dictionary, the `Delegate` must be cast to `StyleDel<T>` first - whatever `T` might be at that moment.

---

### The situation

After all of the styling is initialised and stored, the styling must be applied (using the `StyleDel`s). For this I made a function `StyleControl(control)`.

This function looks at the type of the control (e.g. a `Button`) and finds the corresponding `StyleDel` from the `Dictionary`, which in its turn applies the (`Button`-)styling.

```
public void StyleControl<T>(T control) where T : Control
{
    Delegate storedDel;
    if (_dict.TryGetValue(control.GetType(), out storedDel))
    {
        // Cast Delegate to StyleDel
        var styleDel = (StyleDel<T>) storedDel;

        // Execute StyleDel
        styleDel(control);
    }
}
```

The `StyleDel`s are added to the dictionary with the `Add` function below:

```
public bool Add<T>(StyleDel<T> styleDel) where T : Control
{
    var inDict = _dict.ContainsKey(typeof(T)); 
    if (!inDict) _dict[typeof(T)] = styleDel;
    return !inDict;
}
```

And the `StyleControl` function is called by another function, which makes sure everything is styled recursively:

```
public void Style<T>(T parent) where T : Control
{
    StyleControl(parent);

    // The problem might have to do with this
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls) Style(child);
}
```

---

### The problem

An `InvalidCastException` is thrown, saying a `StyleDel<Button>` cannot be converted to `StyleDel<Control>`. So I believe it's saying that `T` is seen as a `Control` at this point, while it's actually a `Button`.

**How do I cast this `Delegate` to a `StyleDel<Button>` successfully?**

Comment: Can you post the code of where the delegate is first added to the Dictionary?

Comment: How are you calling the method? Either implicitly or explicitly, you're calling with `T` as `Control`.

Comment: I'd say the issue is where you're adding the delegate to the dictionary, the following, for example, works: `_dict.Add(typeof(Button), (StyleDel<Button>)((Button b) => b.AutoEllipsis = true));`

Comment: @Abion47 I've put that code in the question

Comment: @CharlesMager For that I use another function to style everything recusively: `void Style<T>(T parent) where T : Control { StyleControl(parent); /* ... */ }`

Comment: @Duncan well, whatever code is in there is calling with `T` as `Control` and `control.GetType()` is `typeof(Button)`, so there's your mismatch.

Comment: @CharlesMager I've added the whole recursive method in my question. Could the problem be caused by the `Control child` part in the foreach perhaps?

Comment: @Abion47 Because the Type should not be `Control` in this case. If the control is of type `Button`, `T` should be `Button` and not `Control`. In any other situation you would be right, but here the Type is very important.

Comment: @Duncan yep, that's it. You're getting the same result as if you replaced the generic with `Control`. Not immediately obvious how it can be resolved without using some reflection to call the delegate.

Comment: @CharlesMager Interesting. Hopefully someone knows a solution for that

Comment: @Abion47 I'm not sure what you mean by that. The point of this solution is not having to cast directly to `Button` (or any other control). If `T` is of type `Control`, then the cast to `StyleDel<T>` would become a cast to `Style<Control>` instead of `Style<Button>` which are two totally different delegates

Comment: You're currently calling the StyleControl method with `Control` as the type argument by the looks of it. With your current approach, I can only see Reflection as working, not very pretty, like: `var type = controlToBeStyled.GetType();

            var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("StyleControl").MakeGenericMethod(type);
            method.Invoke(null, new[] { controlToBeStyled });`, where "Program" here is just the name of the containing class. Not very pretty or performant or necessarily that maintainable. Maybe there;s another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a level of inderection; create a lambda that calls your delegate casting the argument to the right type:

```
Dictionary<Type, StyleDel<Control>> _dict = ...

public bool Add<T>(StyleDel<T> styleDel) where T : Control
{
    var inDict = _dict.ContainsKey(typeof(T)); 
    if (!inDict) _dict[typeof(T)] = d => StyleDel((T)d);
    return inDict;
}
```

At first glance this might seem to not be type safe, but in this particular case it will be because the delegate is stored in a dictionary with the argument's true type as it's key. Intended usage will therefore always ensure that the delegate is always called with a correctly typed argument and a runtime cast exception will not happen.

Comment: @CharlesMager No, because the dictionary is now `Dictionary<Type, StyleDel<Control>>`. Forgot to add that bit, edited answer.

Comment: Then you still have the same issue that a `StyleDel<Button>` is not a `StyleDel<Control>`. This wouldn't compile.

Comment: @CharlesMager This compiles and runs just fine. You are simply getting a `MyDel<Button>` and storing it as a `MyDel<Control>` with an additional call and an argument cast that will always succeed. The lamba argument `d` when adding to the dictionary is implicitly typed `Control` because thats the dictionary's type. You simply cast it to the right type and call the supplied delegate. Its fool proof.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry - I missed that `d` is actually `Control` in this case. You're losing some of the type safety in that if you call the `StyleDel<Control>` with anything other than a `Button` then you'll get a runtime exception on casting the `Control` to `Button` - you may as well remove the generic `T` from `StyleDel<T>` - but I suppose it does work in this case! +1

Comment: @CharlesMager No, you don't want to remove `T` because that's precisely what enforces that a `StyleDel<Button>` is stored with a `typeof(Button)` key and nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124813/discussion-between-inbetween-and-charles-mager).